# What is causing Segmentation fault (core dumped)? and how do I fix it?

Tags: linux, assembly

this is my code, it's supposed to be so the user add, multiply, divide or subtract two integers. when ever i execute it i can enter both integers and the operator and even the 'answer' string prints out but instead of printing out the actual answer to the problem is says 'Segmentation fault (core dumped). I understand that this happens when the program tries to use or write to memory that it doesn't have access to. I'm kind of new to assembly language, it took my hours to get this far. Please help me.

```
1 ; Function: adds, subtracts, divides or multiplies two
2 ; integers the user inputs
3 ;
4 ;
5 ; --------------------------------------------------------------------------    --
6
7 %include "CPsub32.inc"
8 %include "Macros_CPsub32.inc"
9
10 section .data
11
12 CRLF     db 0Ah,0Dh,00h
13 prompt1  db 0Ah,0Dh,'Please enter an Integer?',0Ah,0Dh,00h
14 prompt2  db 0Ah,0Dh,'Please enter an Operator?',0Ah,0Dh,00h
15 answer   db 0Ah,0Dh,'The answer is: ',0Ah,0Dh,00h
16
17 operand1 DD 0d
18 operand2 DD 0d
19 operator db 00h
20 result   DD 0d
21
22
23 ipbuffer db "   "
24 ipbuflen equ $-ipbuffer
25
26
27 section   .text
28           global main
29
30 main      equ   $
31           mov   edx, prompt1            ;move prompt1 to reg edx
32           call  WriteString             ;write out prompt1
33           mov   edx, ipbuffer
34           mov   ecx, ipbuflen
35
36           call  ReadString              ;read users input (operand1)
37           mov   edx, ipbuffer
38           mov   ecx, 4                  ;something with 4 bytes in reg ecx
39           call  ParseDecimal32          ;change users input (op1) into decim    al
40           mov   dword [operand1], eax   ;load user input (op1) into operand1    ?
41
42           mov   edx, prompt2            ;move prompt2 to reg edx
43           call  WriteString             ;write out prompt2
44           mov   edx, ipbuffer
45           mov   ecx, ipbuflen
46
47           call  ReadString              ;read user input (operator)
48           mov   edx, [ipbuffer]
49           mov   [operator], dl          ;move user input (operator) to opera    tor
50
51           mov   edx, prompt1            ;move prompt1 to reg edx again
52           call  WriteString             ;write out promt1 again
53           mov   edx, ipbuffer
54           mov   ecx, ipbuflen
55
56           call  ReadString              ;read users input (operand2)
57           mov   edx, ipbuffer
58           mov   ecx, 4                  ;something with 4 bytes in reg ecx
59           call  ParseDecimal32          ;change user input (op2) into decima    l
60           mov   dword [operand2], eax   ;move user input (op2) into operand2    ?
61
62           mov   edx, answer             ;move answer to reg edx
63           call  WriteString             ;write out "answer is"
64           mov   edx, ipbuffer
65           mov   ecx, ipbuflen
66
67           mov   dl, [operator]          ;move operator to dl
68           mov   eax, [operand1]         ;move operand1 to eax
69           mov   ebx, [operand2]         ;move operand2 to ebx
70
71
72           cmp   dl, 2Bh         ;is this a + sign
73           je    myAdd
74           cmp   dl, 2Dh  ;is this a - sign
75           je    mySub
76           cmp   dl, 2Ah  ;is this a * sign
77           je    myMul
78           cmp   dl, 2Fh  ;is this a / sign
79           je    myDiv
80
81           mov   eax, [result]   ;mov result to reg eax
82           call  WriteString     ;write out the result
83           mov   edx, ipbuffer
84           mov   ecx, ipbuflen
85
86           jmp   myExit
87
88 myAdd   equ   $
89         add     eax,ebx                 ;add operand1 and operand2
90         mov     dword[result],eax       ;move sum to result
91
92 mySub   equ     $
93         sub     eax,ebx                 ;subtract operand1 and operand2
94         mov     dword [result], eax
95
96 myDiv   equ     $
97         mov     ecx, ebx
98         div     byte[ecx]                       ;divide operand1 by operand2
99         mov     dword [result], eax
100
101 myMul   equ     $
102         xor     edx,edx
103         mul     byte[ebx]                       ;multiply operand1 and operand2
104         mov     dword [result], eax
105
106 myExit    equ   $
```

Comment: Run your program in GDB and share the result of command "backtrace" and "info registers" at the time of segmentation fault occurred.

Comment: Depending on operator, you jump to `myAdd` or whatever. How do you get back from there? Looks like it will fall through, do all the other operations, then fall off the end. This will certainly segfault. I think your `myDiv` and `myMul` will segfault also. I don't think you want to either `div` or `mul` by a byte - certainly not one located in memory you (probably) don't have access to.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like `edx` contains a valid string pointer when you execute `call  WriteString     ;write out the result`  (assuming that you had ever got there).

Comment: how would i get back after the myAdd, mySub, etc.?

Comment: Well `jmp myDisplay` might do it - a label you'll have to add around line 80. As Michael points out, your last `WriteString` doesn't look right. We have no idea what Prof. Cullen calls his "WriteInt" routine, but presumably there is one. Don't forget to exit cleanly - there's probably a macro for that, too...

Comment: frank kotler, you know prof cullen?

Comment: No. Only what I find from googling the .inc file. http://cullenprogramming.homelinux.com/coms239asm.html The link at the bottom is 404. Looks like Masm syntax but switched to Nasm? Unusual to see carriage returns in Linux code. Good luck.